# Assigning "awk" or "nawk" to a variable in a shell script

Tags: linux, awk, solaris

I have a script to be run on both Solaris and Red Hat systems. I want to use "nawk" in Solaris and "awk" in Red Hat systems as text processing tool. For that, I have a code snippet as below in my script:

```
...
if [ "$SYSTEM_OS" = "SunOS" ]; then
cibi_seperator="nawk"
elif [ "$SYSTEM_OS" = "Linux"  ]; then
cibi_seperator="awk"
fi
...
```

When I run the script, I get following errors:

```
    bash-3.00$ ./cibi_awk_both_os.sh 
./cibi_awk_both_os.sh: line 75: -F,: command not found
./cibi_awk_both_os.sh: line 77: -F: command not found
./cibi_awk_both_os.sh: line 77: -F=: command not found
./cibi_awk_both_os.sh: line 77: -v: command not found
./cibi_awk_both_os.sh: line 79: -F,: command not found
./cibi_awk_both_os.sh: line 85: -F,: command not found
./cibi_awk_both_os.sh: line 107: -F,: command not found
./cibi_awk_both_os.sh: line 108: -F,: command not found
```

75th line of the script:

```
$cibi_seperator -F, 'NR==1,NR==2{print $0;}' cibi.csv > section_header.csv
```

All the other problematic lines (77, 79, 85, 107, 108) use also the variable $cibi_seperator.
How to use this variable correctly in my script?
Thanks,
Murat

Comment: It seems that `cibi_seperator` wasn't set, try print it value after your `if ... elif ... fi`.

Comment: The obvious reason would be that `SYSTEM_OS` was neither SunOS nor Linux, but nobody can tell much without the rest of the script. If you can make a minimal example that demonstrates the issue it would help even more.

Comment: Standard warning: this assumes that the `awk`/`nawk` in the path will be what you expect and not the Awesome Word Kombinator anagram generating program in `/opt/bin`. Maybe consider explicitly setting it to `**/usr/bin/**awk` or similar. (Yes, this comes with its own set of problems.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the problem:
I set the parameter:

```
SYSTEM_OS=`uname -a`
```

before the if statement. Whereas, I should have set it to:

```
SYSTEM_OS=`uname -s`
```

Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: If this solved your problem, consider accepting your solution - someone might encounter the same problem in the future.

Comment: Or just `SYSTEM_OS=\`uname\``. But best would probably be to put a `PATH=$(getconf PATH):$PATH` at the beginning of your script and make sure your script is interpreted by a standard sh and not the Bourne shell (for instance by adding a `: ^ false || exec ksh - "$0" ${1+"$@"}` after the she-bang if you're using a `#! /bin/sh -` she-bang). To make sure you get a POSIX environment instead of the antiquated utilities found in /bin on Solaris 10 and earlier.

Answer (score 0):

```
case "$SYSTEM_OS" in
(SunOS)
    cibi_separator=nawk;;
(Linux)
    cibi_separator=awk;;
(*)
    echo "[$SYSTEM_OS] unsupported"; exit 1;;
esac

...

$cibi_separator -F, 'NR==1,NR==2{print $0;}' cibi.csv > section_header.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have used

```
cibi_seperator="awk" # general case, use plain awk

if [ "$SYSTEM_OS" = "SunOS" ]; then
cibi_seperator="nawk"
elif [ "$SYSTEM_OS" = "fooOS"  ]; then
cibi_seperator="/bin/special/awk"
elif ...
fi
```

This way, cibi_seperator is always set, test is done only for OS that need special awk (like solaris).